# sqlite3 selecting values based on python variables

Tags: database, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

I am trying to select a value from my python SQL table based on a variable that the user inputs, through Tkinter. My database has a column named employee_username and has the employee's usernames and their password in 1 row. Username is entered by the user in a tkinter window

My code looks like this:

```
import sqlite3
import password_database
import tkinter

conn = sqlite3.connect('passwordDb.db')
c = conn.cursor()
username=entry_user.get()
password=entry_user.get()
database_username=c.execute(SELECT * FROM passwordDb WHERE 
employee_username=username)

if database_username!=' ':
   print('you entered a username which is not in the database')
else:
   running=True
```

When I run this code I am not able to get any results. How do I manage to check if the value the user enters is in my database and how to I retrieve employee's password attached to the username.
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you get error message ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: Query should be in `" "` - `execute("SELECT * FROM passwordDb WHERE employee_username=?", (username, ))`

Comment: Note that `get` is one time acquiring of string in an entry widget. `username` and `password` won't self-synchronize. You need to call `get` each time they need to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete but I guess i understand you.

Before you query the database, you need to strip of white spaces from the username or the input

```
username = input("username")
db_username = username.strip() #this removes the white space

# you can then check to see if the username is none...

records = cur.fetchall(); # this would return all matching records, loop through

if not database_user is None:
    ...
else:
    print("your username is bad")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see few mistakes

First: query should be as string, and it should have `?` and `username` should be tuple `(username, )` as argument

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM passwordDb WHERE employee_username=?", (username, ))
```

Second: you have to use `fetchall()` or fetchone()` to get list with results or first result.

```
rows = cur.fetchall()

row = cur.fetchone()
```

Third: `execute()` doesn't have to return value so there is no sense to comparer with string `" "`. fetchall()`/`fetchone()` returns row(s) with result(s) so you can check how many rows it returned.

```
rows = cur.fetchall()

if len(rows) != 1:
   print("your username is bad or duplicate")
```

or

```
rows = cur.fetchall()

if cur.rowcount != 1:
   print("your username is bad or duplicate")
```